# CakePHP, Post to two URLs with one click

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp, http-post

I was wondering if I could post to two different URLs with one click of a button?
What I am trying to accomplish is to make a birthday website for my friend. People could come on site and write something about him. To keep things organized, I made two models, User and Message. Now, what I am trying to accomplish if to be able to give a single form which takes User data (name and email) and Message (description) and updates both the tables. Thanks in advance.

I am willing to do stuff from javascript too! But I haven't studied any javascript as such so if it is possible with JavaScript, please provide clear instructions too. Thanks!

Comment: Why not update both models from one controller?

Comment: I am still in the learning stages and don't know if its possible. Should I make a new controller, say, FormsController which handles the job?

Comment: Yes. Models are independend from the controller. I'T a while ago since i used Cake, but i think their name sheme implies that every controller belongs to a model. But you can use other models in a controller, too.

Comment: Please show me how in the answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use models in others controllers just, define it on controller `uses` array like

```
class controller extends AppController {

  public $uses = array('Model1', 'Model2');

  public function doSomething() {

       debug($this->Model1);
       debug($this->Model2);

  }
```

}

Or if models are related, it's better to take through relationship like

```
 $this->Model1->Model2->save();
```

You should read documentation [model asociations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) to understand how basic model works.

To answer your question how to call another url there is [requestAction](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::requestAction) but use it with caution, because it takes all way through bootsrap process, so it's slow.

Answer (score 1):

Use a single Form, with data for both models, and use `$this->User->saveAssociated($this->request->data)`

It will save both User and Message data in one shot, no need for 2 submits.